# Predicting exponentially distributed output with multi inputs with the help of neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science-model

I want to construct a Neural network regression model for data (8 inputs and 1 output). My problem is that my output has exponential distribution. When I normalized it in 'log scale' or 'min-max scale' error is decreasing but the error in my original-output is rising by 10 times. How to fit this data. Are there any other transformations I can try on my data or any other algorithms or models which will help me.

[This is the correlation plot without scaling the output, it has exponential distribution. The last one is the output variable in the plot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtltD.jpg)

[This is the correlation plot for log scaled output which has gaussian distribution, the error is decreasing in this case but still high when converted to original data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu0c8.jpg)